# Default Android Emulator has disappeared

Tags: android, xamarin, emulation, android-virtual-device

### help

Im working in Visual studio with Xamarin. And somehow when I got errors concerning the emulator not functioning properly, the default emulator which was shown in the AVD manager disappeared. (I didnt delete it by myself). Now I'm wondering how to retrieve it back. Connecting my phone with xamarin doesn't work properly, cause I get an error like "Resource does not contain a definition for Main". Thats'why I want to use an AVD. Because the default emulator is disappeared I made an own AVD, but I can only use Android Wear Itom Image CPU as CPU/ABI.

My question is: How do I get the default emulator back?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

-Tools -> Android -> Android Emulator Manager

-Switch to the tab "Device Definitions" and click on Create device

-Create a device :)

-Switch back to the tab "Android Virtual Devices"

-Click on create

-Choose the definition you created just before.

I think on order to get the default profiles back you would need to reinstall the Android SDK

---

For to get it working with you mobile phone go to
-Tools -> Android -> Android SDK Manager

-Make sure everything is up-to-date

-Make sure you have the correct SDK version installed.

-Switch to tab "Tools"

-Update everything

-Make sure you have the correct build-tools version installed.

-(Not sure about this one)Under Extras check Google USB Driver